# How can I display the content of two arrays alternating?

Tags: php, arrays

This is `array1`:

```
array(4) {
  ["1234"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["animal"]=>
    string(19) "cat"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "fred"
    ["food"]=>
    string(32) "milk"
  }
}
```

and this is `array2`:

```
array(4) {
   ["1234"]=>
   array(5) {
     ["animal"]=>
     string(19) "dog"
     ["name"]=>
     string(12) "sam"
     ["food"]=>
     string(32) "chicken"
   }
```

I want to display the content alternately.

So the result should be:

```
cat
dog
fred
sam
milk
chicken
```

The difficult thing is, that I never know the content of the arrays (I only know that the keys of `array1` always match the keys of `array2`. I can have an output for each array (`$array1["1234"]` and `$array2["1234"]`) but I couldn't find any tutorial about this topic.

Comment: please add language tag

Comment: @nullpointer: Sorry, added it!

Comment: not a PHP developer, but logic seems in Java would be like :
`int len = array1.length;
 for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    if(i%2==0)
      System.out.println(array1[i]);
   else
      System.out.println(array2[i]);
  }`

Comment: @nullpointer that way you would get 3 out of 6 outputs in the example

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco oh I thought an alternate output from either of them..true...I messed up :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a foreach loop and just print one after the other:

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){

    echo $array1[$key].PHP_EOL; //or $value
    echo $array2[$key].PHP_EOL; //PHP_EOL just print a newline character



}
```

in a case like your example where you have 2-dimensional (or n-dimensional where n > 1) you might add nested foreach loop like this (keep nesting till loops  = n):

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){

    foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue ){

        echo $array1[$key][$innerKey].PHP_EOL; //or $innerValue
        echo $array2[$key][$innerKey].PHP_EOL; //PHP_EOL just print a newline character

    }

}
```

like this [working example](https://ideone.com/MhgI2k)

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me the output: `ArrayArrayArrayArray..`

Comment: can you clarify a little, your arays would always be 2-dimensional?

Comment: Yes this is working very well! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96497/discussion-between-jarla-and-juan-antonio-orozco).